# How to start node.js app and then return to command line and navigate

Tags: node.js, nginx, centos

**Background:** I'm running `nginx` on `CentOS` with a `node.js` backend.

I type `node server.js` to start my app.  However after I start my app I lose the ability to type anything else or navigate my server.  The only way I can get back to the command line is to stop my app by typing `control c`.  Then I can maintain and navigate with `CentOS` normally until I start my app again.

Is there a way to start my app and then go back to `CentOS` without it locking everything up while `server.js` is running?  Maybe I'm missing something obvious.  Sorry for the noob question!

Comment: No there is not. You need to create another connection to your server using another terminal tab.

Comment: Another way is installing `forever` and starting your script with it. Here's [more about it](https://mrvautin.com/running-nodejs-applications-in-production-forever-vs-supervisord-vs-pm2/).

Comment: I believe you are just learning and this is a developmental application. In real production apps, the node.js is run as a background service/daemon with some process manager like PM2

Comment: Ok no problem.  So all I have to do is open another terminal.  Perfect!  I knew there had to be a way to get back to `CentOS`.

Comment: Try something like tmux, it'll make your life easier

Answer (score 1):

Use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) or [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to run the app in the background. You can also use `nohup` like the following example.

```
nohup node server.js &
```

This will run the node app in the background and you will be able to use the command-line shell.